# smarty variable in JavaScript syntax correction

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to use this variable in JavaScript but I am getting syntax error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal} 
$.get("mypage.php", { phone:{/literal} "{$smarty.request.phone}"{literal},
time:{/literal}"{$smarty.request.time}"{literal} } );
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: just pasted the relevant code here rest of jquery libs are already included so sticking to the point

Comment: What does the code look like in the browser (i.e. after Smarty is done with it)? That's the only thing relevant to JS.

Comment: the earliar code was also the actual code only 1 ")" was missing this is just another part of the code that i have printed now. And the exact error phrase is not pasted but it was syntax error and the line that produced error is already pasted here. THX for no need down vote.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, it was the actual code, sure; except that half of it was missing. *RIIIIGHT.*

Comment: Sorry man if you are angry but with all due respect the so called Half   is pretty useless but again thx to you i modified the code as you pointed if you still want i will post the actual code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{literal} 
<script type="text/javascript">

$.get("mypage.php", 
{ phone:"{$smarty.request.phone}"}
);
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? It doesn't look like it would work at all to me?! Unless it's using some feature I've never seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, with Smarty3 you do not need to use `{literal}` anymore in JS and CSS code blocks. In Smarty3, braces surrounded with white-spaces are not parsed by Smarty, so:

```
if (a == b) { return c; } // Is not parsed by Smarty3
if (a == b) { return {$c}; } // Only {$c} is parsed
if (a == b) {return c;} // This is parsed because there are no white-spaces near braces.
```

Ref: http://www.smarty.net/v3_overview, "{" and "}" (Javascript) Auto-Escapement